# getJson restricting number of rows in local host (XAMPP)

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

I switched to `XAMPP` from a web server. Used `getJson` to encode the rows fetched from the `mysql` table . I found out that when using the local host the number of rows have been restricted to a weird 53. The same code perfectly works on the web server. I tried increasing max execution time to 5000 , didn't help .
My SQL table has 141 rows.

```
<?php
include('../conn.php');
 $sql = "SELECT test_name,amount FROM lab_test order by sl";
 $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql)  or die( mysqli_error($conn));
 $i=0;
     while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
     {
         $entry[$i][0]=$row['test_name'];
         $entry[$i][1]=$row['amount'];
         $i++;
     }
echo json_encode($entry);
?>
```

It worked on restricting the row count to 53

```
<?php
include('../conn.php');
 $sql = "SELECT test_name,amount FROM lab_test order by sl";
 $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql)  or die( mysqli_error($conn));
 $i=0;
     while($i<=52)
     {
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
         $entry[$i][0]=$row['test_name'];
         $entry[$i][1]=$row['amount'];
         $i++;
     }
echo json_encode($
?>
```

Here's my calling code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //dynamic population of lab tests
        $.getJSON("./ajaxLabTestTable.php", function(response){
            console.log("tests");
            $.each(response, function(){
                var tr="<tr>";
                var td0="<td class="+JSON.stringify("chk")+"><input type="+JSON.stringify("checkbox")+"></td>";
                var td1="<td>"+this[0]+"</td>";
                var td2="<td align="+JSON.stringify("right")+">"+this[1]+"</td></tr>";
                var opt = tr+td0+td1+td2; 
                $("#lab_tests").append(opt);
            });
        });
    });
```

It has to be something to with a configuration file.

Comment: because you are executing a loop which is running 53 times

Comment: Sorry , you haven't understood my problem , the first code snippet is what i actually intended to do , but it isn't working on the localhost , but works on the web server. On debugging i came to that threshold of 53 rows.

Comment: what happend if you var_dump($result)?. Does it show all or just 53 rows?another comment, don't use mysqli, use PDO

Comment: So what exactly does "it isn't working" mean? If you're getting an error, what is the exact error?

Comment: @JulianMendez Sure , i'll have to take into security

Comment: @PatrickQ , there is no error on the console , it just doesn't enter   $.getJSON function

Comment: I'm going to assume that you mean it doesn't enter the _callback_ function, which is actually a _success_ callback.  You should check your network tab to see what the actual response from the server is. If it is anything besides valid JSON (say, for example, an error message), then the callback will not run.

Comment: @PatrickQ , on the web server this code works perfectly fine , no errors . just something weird on XAMPP. The JSON is absolutely valid

Comment: Okay, but that doesn't address what I said. When you run this and it doesn't work, you should look at your network tab in your browser's developer tool and look at what the response is for the ajax request.

Comment: @PatrickQ I dont get any response.

Comment: @PatrickQ, but when i restrict the loop to 52 it gives the JSON in the response.

Comment: Take the ajax out of the equation.  Request the file directly in your browser.  Check the response status code.  Check your apache error logs.